# Use Tag input metabox style for Categories

Tags: categories, metabox, tags

I am using Categories to create news timelines, For example http://newslines.org/misha-collins/ (check the cloud at the bottom of the page for more examples)

The problem is in the Add Post screen. The Categories input metabox uses checkboxes. As the list of categories grows, scrolling through this list is becoming very timeconsuming.

I could convert the Categories to Tags (which is very easy) so that I could use the Tag input metabox, which has an ajax autocomplete, but then I would have to change the theme code to throughout the site so that it would display tags instead of categories.

So I was wondering if I could just change the Category Metabox to have the same Ajax autocomplete style as the Tags Metabox. All advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the category metabox. 
You can create custom metabox as per your need which contains all categories in proper layout.
Also you can search for plugins, say HTML5 category selector plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-html5-category-selector/

Comment: Please vote up and mark this as correct.

Comment: I don't have enough points to vote up.